# Can I publish a book under one company when I have published a book under another?

Tags: publishing, publisher

I published two books with a publishing company, and I was wondering whether I could publish my next one with a different one. Can I?

Answer (score 6):

As long as you don't have a contract specifying that your next N books must be with Copmany A, there's no reason you can't go with Company B.

If you mean that you self-published and want to change the imprint, you can do that too; just talk to your accountant to make sure you aren't garbling things for tax purposes.